# AutoIt CaptureScreen file location

Tags: vba, automation, autoit

I have the following AutoIt script:

```
Run("Notepad.exe", @WindowsDir, @SW_MAXIMIZE)
Sleep(1000)
Send("Just a test")
$anPos = WinGetClientSize("")
$nLeft = 0
$nTop = 0
$nRight = $anPos[0]
$nBottom = $anPos[1]
$sFileName = "test.jpg"
DllCall("captdll.dll", "int:cdecl", "CaptureScreen", "str", $sFileName, "int", 85)
```

The script seems to run OK, but I cannot locate the test.jpg file anywhere. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of Sleep(1000) you can use [`WinWaitActive`](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinWaitActive.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did not have captdll installed correctly, that was the problem.